# CRUD : update method doesn't work [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, crud

I faced an issue with update method. I'm working on a spring boot angular project so update doesnt work on frontend my code looking logic can someone gie me an idea about this issue

**user.service**

```
 updateProfile(userData: SignUpData, id: string ): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.patch( API_URL + 'update/' + id, userData, httpOptions);
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
form: any = {};
  id: string;
  errorMessage = '';
  currentUser: any;

  constructor(private userservice: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();
  }
 onSubmit() {

    const {adresse1, ...rest} = this.form;

    const userData: SignUpData = {...rest, adresses: [adresse1]};

    this.userservice.updateProfile(userData, this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);

      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
      }
    );
  }
```

**Interceptor.ts**

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {

      authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });


    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?  Is the request sent to the backend (web developer console)? Do you have a logging in the backend controller?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource, yeah I have logged in

Comment: then you have to figure out how to authenticate . Perhaps you have to put a (jwt) token in your request header.

Comment: I send the Authorization: Bearer in req header but still not working

Comment: what does httpOptions contain?

Comment: const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

Comment: So you are overwriting headers there..? Right? So how does auth work? Or is there an interceptor somewhere? (PS: Setting that header is probably not needed btw)

Comment: Yeah auth works. I add interceptor to my question you can chechk it

Comment: You have to look at your backend, why the backend sends a "401 Unauthorized "..

Comment: All users had the preAuthourized to update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I try to logout & log in and that's working because first I didn't get user id so I add `this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();` without refresh authenticate so GET was always returning 401 not found. I hope this answer can help people that have the same issue And thank you guys for your replies